# Syllables with e caduc

Tags: grammaire

I'm reading L'Albatros by Charles Baudelaire and got confused at the syllables.

[Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27albatros_(poem)) says:

> It is built with four alexandrins quatrains with crossed Rhymes (ABAB
> type), alternating feminine and masculine noun genders.

which means, each line shall have 12 syllables.

I don't quite get it.

For example this line, I could only find 11:

> Laissent piteusement leurs grandes ailes blanches

> Laissent  · pi · teu · se · ment  · leurs  · gran · des  · ai · les  · blanches

I suppose *Laissent* has only 1 syllable, as it is not ending with *e*, so there's no *e caduc*.

I'm also confused at the last line,

> Ses ailes de géant l'empêchent de marcher.

> Ses  · ai · les  · de  · gé · ant  · l'em · pêchent  · de  · mar · cher.

seems also only has 11 syllables?

Or am I wrong that in both cases, *Laissent* and *l'empêchent* are considered to have an *e caduc* as the ending *-ent* is the same as *-e*?

The full text of the poem is:

> Souvent, pour s’amuser, les hommes d’équipage
> Prennent des albatros, vastes oiseaux des mers,
> Qui suivent, indolents compagnons de voyage,
> Le navire glissant sur les gouffres amers.
>
> À peine les ont-ils déposés sur les planches,
> Que ces rois de l'azur, maladroits et honteux,
> Laissent piteusement leurs grandes ailes blanches
> Comme des avirons traîner à côté d'eux.
>
> Ce voyageur ailé, comme il est gauche et veule !
> Lui, naguère si beau, qu'il est comique et laid !
> L'un agace son bec avec un brûle-gueule,
> L'autre mime, en boitant, l'infirme qui volait !
>
> Le Poète est semblable au prince des nuées
> Qui hante la tempête et se rit de l'archer ;
> Exilé sur le sol au milieu des huées,
> Ses ailes de géant l'empêchent de marcher.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Or am I wrong that in both cases, *Laissent* and *l'empêchent* are considered to have an e caduc as the ending -ent is the same as -e?

Yes, inside a verse they are the same as *-e followed by a consonant* in that they are an "e caduc" without "elision". See Wikipedia: [Versification française § Règle du e caduc](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Versification_fran%C3%A7aise#R%C3%A8gle_du_e_caduc):

> À l'intérieur du vers, le e caduc en fin de mot ne compte pas toujours
> comme une syllabe (élision non systématique du e caduc final d'un
> mot) : il y a élision, et la dernière syllabe ne compte pas, quand le
> son « e » écrit « -e » est suivi par une voyelle ou un h muet ; **il n'y
> a pas élision**, et la dernière syllabe compte, quand le son « e » écrit
> « -e » est suivi par une consonne, ou quand le son « e » est
> orthographié « -es » **ou « -ent »**

So: lai.ssent / pê.chent

Note: the version [sung by Léo Ferré](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b6IIRxSPRIA) is a pretty pure example of how it scans "by the rules".

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vers)

> On peut illustrer ces règles « scolaires » minimales par la transcription approximative (en API) des vers suivants extraits du poème LIII « L'Invitation au voyage » de Charles Baudelaire (Les Fleurs du Mal, « Spleen et Idéal ») :
>
> — Les soleils couchants
>
> Revêtent les champs
> Les canaux, la ville entièr(e),
> D'hyacinthe et d'or ;
> Le monde s'endort
> Dans une chaude lumière.
> Là tout n'est qu'ordre et beauté,
> Luxe, calme et volupté.
> [le sɔlɛj kuʃɑ̃]
>
> [ʁəvɛtə le ʃɑ̃]  5 syll.

It follows that « laissent » has two syllables.